# How can i implement a particular style of URLs in Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes

I am scratching my head and couldn't figure this out myself. I have seen a particular style of navigation i.e. URL that i find very good in terms of SEO but can't think of anyway to implement in Rails. I have developed few apps in Rails so know about rails routing but no nothing about php in which the particular website is made in.

So You land on the main page as 
www.xyz.com

Then if you click on any side bar links to see particular brand of mobiles for e.g Samsung, you click samsung mobile link and the url goes to 
www.xyv.com/samsung_mobile_prices

Ok now thinking from rails perspective we are viewing samsung mobile object list view. When we click a particular samsung model for e.g samsung Galaxy J then url changes to
www.xyz.com/samsung_galaxy_j

In Rails I can get 
www.xyz.com/samsung_mobile_prices/samsung_galaxy_j

but can't seems to understand how to achieve
www.xyz.com/samsung_galaxy_j

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thats easy. All you have to do it is to forward all the upcoming request (Except `/`) to its respective controller action like `products#show`.This is what i am saying

```
 match ":id" => 'products#show' , via: :get , as: 'product_direct_url'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is something called [`clean_urls`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL) (alternatively called `slugging`):

> Clean URLs, RESTful URLs, user-friendly URLs or SEO-friendly URLs are
>   purely structural URLs that do not contain a query string [e.g.,
>   action=delete&id=91] and instead contain only the path of the resource
>   (after the scheme [e.g., http] and the authority [e.g., example.org]).

What you're asking is how to apply app-wide slugs (slugs on `domain.com/[slug]`, as opposed to `domain.com/controller/[slug]`)

---

There are two steps to doing this -

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
root: "controller#action"
... # -> other routes first

#This HAS to be last (otherwise Rails will think every URL is a request to this route)
resources :products, path: "", only: "show"
```

--

**Slugs**

With the routes above, you'll be able to access `domain.com/xyz_product`

In order to get this to work, you need to be able to call your product `ids` / `slugs` within your controller / model. To do this, I would *highly* recommend using the [`friendly_id` gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

The big problem about slugging in Rails is by default, the `find` method only searches `id`, not `slugs`. The `friendly_id` gem addresses it:

```
#app/models/product.rb
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This means you'll be able to call:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def show
    product = Product.find params[:id] #-> id can be a slug or a number :)
end
```

Comment: It certainly address the /:id part but that particular website even managed to show the queried / search results with url like
www.xyz.com/samsung_mobile_prices     for all samsung mobiles among all mobiles
and 
www.xyz.com/3GB-RAM_Mobile-Phones     for all mobiles having 3GB or more of ram.

How it was able to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - can you be a little clearer?